# How to store index of duplicated rows in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataset looks like below:

```
+--------+----------+-----------+--------------------+
|        | FST_NAME | LAST_NAME |     EMAIL_ADDR     |
+--------+----------+-----------+--------------------+
| ROW_ID |          |           |                    |
| 1-123  | Will     | Smith     | will.smith@abc.com |
| 1-124  | Dan      | Brown     | dan.brown@xyz.com  |
| 1-125  | Will     | Smith     | will.smith@abc.com |
| 1-126  | Dan      | Brown     | dan.brown@xyz.com  |
| 1-127  | Tom      | Cruise    | tom.cruise@abc.com |
| 1-128  | Will     | Smith     | will.smith@abc.com |
+--------+----------+-----------+--------------------+
```

I am trying to count duplicate rows by keeping the first record and store all the duplicated row index in a column.

[image]

I tried below. It gives me the count but i am unable to group the duplicated index.

```
df.groupby(df.columns.tolist(),as_index=False).size()
```

How can I get the duplicated row index?

Comment: please post the input dataframe as text in your question

Comment: @luigigi I have updated the input dataframe.

Comment: You have to create a new dataframe and store the index names as column or perform a multiIndex with two levels (bit over the top in this case though!). This should be done directly after import statement of your datalist. But... tbh... you won't get a df from your dataset because pd throws an error due to duplicates in index names first. So you're question is rigged as it is writing right-now. So.. my suggestion is to show your working code first before we post answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
df.reset_index().groupby(df.columns.tolist())["index"].agg(list).reset_index()
```

To get exactly what you want:

```py
res=df.reset_index().groupby(df.columns.tolist())["index"].agg(list).reset_index().rename(columns={"index": "duplicated"})
res.index=res["duplicated"].str[0].tolist()
res["duplicated"]=res["duplicated"].str[1:]
```

Outputs (dummy data):

```py
#original df:
    a  b
a1  x  4
a2  y  3
b6  z  2
c7  x  4
d   x  4
x   y  3

#transformed one:
    a  b duplicated
a1  x  4    [c7, d]
a2  y  3        [x]
b6  z  2         []
```

Comment: I tweaked it a bit - now I think it's the same.

Answer (score 1):

Not a very efficient way, just that it can be used as a solution

```
df2 = df.drop_duplicates()
```

This will result as df2 =

```
    Name1   Name2
0   Will    Smith
1   Dan     Brown
4   Tom     Cruise
```

Now,

```
lis = []
for i in df2.iterrows():
    lis.append(i[0])
```

This will make `lis = [0, 1, 4]`. All the indexes from 0 to `len(df)` that are not in lis, are the indexes that contain duplicates.

Comment: The second part of the solution could be `lis = df2.index.to_numpy()`

Answer (score 0):

For df like:

```
  FST_NAME L_NAME email
0        w      s    ws
1        d      b    db
2        w      s    ws
3        z      z    zz
```

Get grouped index into lists

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'FST_NAME': ['w', 'd', 'w', 'z'], 'L_NAME': ['s', 'b', 's', 'z'], 'email': ['ws', 'db', 'ws', 'zz']})
df = df.groupby(df.columns.tolist()).apply(lambda row: pd.Series({'duplicated': list(row.index)}))
```

Output:

```
                      duplicated
FST_NAME L_NAME email           
d        b      db           [1]
w        s      ws        [0, 2]
z        z      zz           [3]
```